# pandas dataframe enumerate rows that passed a filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data frame, and I'd like to add a column which is -1 if the row did not pass a filter, or an index if it passed the filter.
For example, in the data frame

```
    b   f   j    passed  new_index
1   12  5   6         Y          0
2   4   99  2         Y          1
3   10  77  16        N         -1
4   4   99  2         Y          2
5   10  77  16        N         -1
6   4   99  2         Y          3
7   10  77  16        N         -1
```

The column `new_index` is the one I added, based on column `passed`.
How do I do this without iterrows?
I created a series `bool4` which is `True` where `passed == Y` and `False` otherwise, and tried:

```
df.loc[bool4, 'new_index'] = df.loc[bool4, 'new_index'].apply([lambda i: i for i in range(sum(bool4))])
```

But it does not update the `new_index` column (leaves it empty).

Comment: Because I want a counter for just those rows that passed the condition.

Comment: Use cumsum to as a counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `eq`, `cumsum`, `add`, and `mask`:

```
df['new_index'] = df.passed.eq('Y').cumsum().add(-1).mask(df.passed == 'N', -1)
```

Output:

```
    b   f   j passed  new_index
1  12   5   6      Y          0
2   4  99   2      Y          1
3  10  77  16      N         -1
4   4  99   2      Y          2
5  10  77  16      N         -1
6   4  99   2      Y          3
7  10  77  16      N         -1
```

Comment: really nice ;) plus1

Comment: @jezrael Thank you.

Comment: Or `df['new_index'] = df.passed.eq('Y').cumsum().add(-1).where(df.passed != 'N', -1)`